# Laravel Intended URL always redirect to index

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am facing a weird (at least for me) problem working with Laravel 5.3.
I try to get the previous link (before user logged in) via session and redirect them back to this link after they succesfuly logged in.

I use this line of code to put in session:

```
Session::put('url.intended', $link);
```

I use this line of code to get from session:

```
Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
```

When i run in development and read from session, i get this url as url.intended:

```
http://example.test/profile/data?_url=%2Fprofile%2Fdata
```

With this url the redirect works fine after login!

Now, when i am in production mode (AWS, ELB, NGINX), i get this url as url.intended:

```
https://example.org/profile/data
```

without ?_url=%2Fprofile%2Fdata so does not work and redirects to homepage.

It's a Laravel 5.3 issue or loadbalancer and nginx setup is wrong?

nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.$host$request_uri redirect;
}


    server {

        listen 80;
            root /var/www/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            server_name  www.example.org;

            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
            }

            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = http) {
                return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }

            location / {
                    sendfile off;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {

                    try_files $uri = 404;
                    fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
                    fastcgi_index /index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            }
    }
```

Is something wrong with my setup or there is something in laravel that i can do, not to remove the ?_url from url.intended ??

Comment: did u find answer?

Comment: No, i still try to figure out what's going on..For sure the problem is in LaravelForceHttpsMiddlewareRedirect cause if i remove it from middleware in kernel, it works, but i miss https. I am try to override somehow the package.

Comment: What is the reason that you need to overwrite it?

Comment: I want to redirect user to the page he asks before login.

Comment: You must know that laravel performance that without your library.

Comment: Yes, but it is behind load balancer and  a lot of problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

If u use Laravel 5.3:

Modify the new Middleware auth redirector

```
/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
```

Change the handle function to look like that:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->intended('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I forget to mention that i use LaravelForceHttpsMiddlewareRedirect package. So maybe to fix it in that package?

Comment: try without it maybe